# How to implement custom authentication (logic) with AWS api gateway and web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, aws-api-gateway, identityserver4

We have a web api project (.net) and we are planing to implement AWS API gateway for handling authentication, caching, e.t.c. But we have a requirement to limit access for a user, for e.g. from a set of ID(s) a user can access data for a subset of ID(s). Now we want to handle authentication only on the AWS side, but I am not sure how can we achieve this considering the requirement we have in hand.

Also, is there any way we can integrate Identity Server 3 with AWS API Gateway for custom authentication.

P.S. Web Api 2.2 hosted on IIS server and back-end is SQL server, so we are using AWS and an api gateway only, we are using our infra for hosting. We do have Identity Server 3 but it is currently used as auth server with another app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you saw Custom Authorization feature in API Gateway. If the Identity Server is publicly addressable, you can authenticate to it using a Lambda authorizer function.

Assuming the client sends some Authorization token in a header, your Lambda function can take the token and authenticate using the Identity Server. You should then be able to translate the access permissions of the caller into an IAM Policy.

If you have an API resource set up like:

`/user/{id}/data`

You can build the authorizer result with access to specific `id` values:

```
{
  "principalId": "yyyyyyyy", // The principal user identification associated with the token sent by the client.
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<restApiId>/<stage>/<httpVerb>/user/id-1/data",
          "arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<restApiId>/<stage>/<httpVerb>/user/id-61/data",
          "arn:aws:execute-api:<regionId>:<accountId>:<restApiId>/<stage>/<httpVerb>/user/id-4/data"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "key": "value",
    "numKey": 1,
    "boolKey": true
  }
}
```